# Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>' react and socket

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I faced this problem while I try to use socket in react ,I know it said I should use
export default instead of module.export but this piece of code exist in socket package itself and  when I change it it through error

I work with node version v14.17.0

these are the packages and react version I use

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

This is the piece of code in socket package which cause this error

```
Object.assign(lookup, {
    Manager,
    Socket,
    io: lookup,
    connect: lookup,
});
if (typeof module !== "undefined") {
    module.exports = lookup;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Downgrade socket.io-client to v4.2.0 for now. The bugs introduced due to ESM builds are being resolved. It may take up to 2-3 days for the latest version to become stable enough to use.

Comment: okay will try this

Comment: that work perfect, thanks @brc-dd

Answer (score 1):

This error means you are trying to use commonJS inside a ES module. Instead try doing:

```
export default lookup
```

When you are instantiating the lookup object. module.exports is the commonJS way to export while webpack uses ES syntax

Comment: I tried this but it show me error that export default can't be nested inside if condition @Austin Burger

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in `socket-io.client@4.3.2`: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/releases/tag/4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

The line `module.exports = lookup;` can be replaced with the following code:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = lookup;
Object.assign(exports, lookup);
```

However, in this case you might face different issues, when, i.e. a calling code tries to directly access some exported value that is altered in some way. In CommonJS such trick are fine, and in ESM they are illegal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that I tried to use the `import` method to load a file while I could only use the `require` method:

```js
import { someObject } from "path";

// Should be converted this way ↓↓↓
const someObject = require ("path");
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's a bad way to solve problems, but I deleted that if statement with export

```
if (typeof module !== "undefined") {
    module.exports = lookup;
}
```

And while everything works fine

Comment: I tried this and it work but I look for a better solution what @brc-dd mentioned above worked perfect